# Issue with Vite + React + MSW

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I having issues getting MSW to work in a react app. I never usually have any issues. I set an environment variable VITE_MOCK to true when running `yarn start:mock`. This should allow  me to kick off some api mocking but I'm falling at he first hurdle.

My handler.js file keeps throwing an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/msw.js?v=d385091a' does not provide an export named 'rest' (at handlers.js:1:10)

This is the handler.js file

```
import { rest } from 'msw';
import { mockedData } from './data/data'

export const handlers = [
  rest.get('https://disney.com', ((req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(
      ctx.status(200),
      ctx.json(mockedData)
    );
  }
  ))
]
```

the

```
import { rest } from 'msw';
```

import seems to be getting messed up by Vite.
Can confirm MSW is installed correctly and in my package.json file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your title should be a clear, specific question without tags.

Comment: Do confirm:  What version of msw are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The msw 2.0 recommends you use http instead of rest. eg:

Before

```
rest.get('/resource', (req, res, ctx) => {})
```

After

```
http.get('/resource', (info) => {})
```